# Want to give a file name in include_once php but with the root address. How?

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on PHP with AJAX. Because of AJAX, one can not say that in which directory you are at in a particular point of time. So to call files I can't use a fixed path and filename. So, I want to give path starting from the root to the file. It is working well.

But the problem comes if I want to include a file. Say I want to include a file test.php like:

```
include_once("http://localhost/sms/test.php");
```

The file is included but the problem is:

```
<?php
   $i = 9;
   include_once("http://localhost/sms/test.php");
?>
```

test.php contains,

```
<?php
  echo $i;
?>
```

This code should give output as:

```
9
```

...but it gives nothing. I know the reason: the browser is requesting the server via separate HTTP request because path contains "http" so server returns HTML output. so $i doesn't exist: no output.

How do I call files in include using their path from root to run AJAX properly?

Comment: `Because of ajax one can not say that in which directory you are at a perticular point of time` this is incorrect: What counts inside the PHP script is always the path of the PHP script, not that of the caller. You can use a relative file path and it will always work.

Comment: Dear @Pekka, can you give me a small example or demo code to understand the implementation.

Comment: show the path of the PHP file that you are calling and I'll write up an example

Comment: @Pekka I am using windows vista, wamp server, file path is c/wamp/www/sms/add/comment.php in this file I am including ../inc/check.php

Comment: That should work: You are using a relative path. Whether you're calling the PHP script via Ajax or not shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Pekka is there any problem if I call javascript by this wayc/wamp/www/sms/js/ajax.js
  Because php files are working now but js is not working.

Answer (score 1):

try `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sms/test.php');`

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* use hostnames in local file paths. Instead, use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), like this:

```
require_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/sms/test.php");
```

This will append something like `/var/www` (or whatever the root path is) to the start of the file path. Also, using `require_once()` instead of `include_once()` is better; if PHP can't find the file to include, it will say so and stop execution, instead of possibly failing silently.

Comment: What I dislike about DOCUMENT_ROOT is that it makes it impossible to move your application around into subdirectories. I would prefer using relative paths wherever possible

Comment: @Pekka You make a good point, although curiously it works for me on a testing server I use; I have multiple sites in `/public_html/[site]` and they all seem to work fine with `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Probably an isolated case.

Comment: mm, but then [site] is Apache's document root for each site, I think that works as designed. I mean you can't move it around in sub-directories e.g. into `/public_html/[site]/apps/v1/appname`

Comment: There aren't any `<virtualhost>` or whatever directories; these are simply folders under a single shared hosting account. Curious.

Comment: hmm, that would indeed be weird!